# why this kotlin code didnt return max index (it always return 0 index)

Tags: kotlin

why this kotlin code didn't return max index (it always return 0 index)

```
fun getMaxModel(): Model {
    val city = modelList
    var modelIndex: Int = 0
    var pop: Float = 0F
    for (i in 0..city.size-1) {
        if (pop < city[i].population.toFloat())
        {
            pop = city[i].population.toFloat()
            modelIndex = i
        }
    }
    return modelList[modelIndex]
}
```

always return 0 index
I need to return max index

Comment: I don't see a bug in this code. Could you provide a full example with data, so we can reproduce it? Also, you actually reinvented [maxBy()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/max-by.html) function. Your whole function could be replaced with simple: `maxBy { it.population }`.

Comment: Well, `maxBy()` was renamed to `maxByOrNull()`.

Comment: Just curious, why the conversion to `Float` for the comparison?

Comment: Also as @broot said, you really don't need to implement this yourself, unless it's educational. `maxByOrNull` and plenty of other collection extensions are available in Kotlin.

Comment: Maybe the reason you're getting this result is that the cities list is empty? Make sure you check your data. Also you don't return an index, you return a `Model` here, so I'm not sure whether you're talking about the value of `modelIndex` or something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can use high order function without need to loop over all datat, as bellow:

```
fun getIndexMinPopModel(): Int {
     return modelList.minByOrNull { it.population }?.let { modelList.indexOf(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
val max = nums.indexOf(nums.max())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function:

```
val max = modelList.maxOrNull()
```

If you need an index of max value then try this:

```
val maxIndex = modelList.indexOf(max)
```

Also I suggest you look at this https://kotlinlang.org/docs/collection-aggregate.html
There is a lot of useful info about how to manipulate with collections in kotlin.
There is also a cool series of exercises from kotlin team, which can help a lot, when you are trying to learn how to work with collections:
https://play.kotlinlang.org/koans/Collections/Introduction/Task.kt